# Difference between property attributes in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

When to use attributes and What is the purpose of each attribute?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Some attributes:

**readonly** - use if you don't want a setter

**retain** - use if you want values assigned to your property to be retained

**copy** - use if you want values assigned to your property to be copied.

**assign** - use if you want new values to be assigned with no retain or copy.

**nonatomic** - use to disable the mechanism that makes property access atomic.  An atomic property is guaranteed to give you a pointer to a real object that still exists or nil.  In a multithreaded environment, a nonatomic property could give you an object that has already been deallocated.